# UIStepper in uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uistepper

In my app I have custom `UITableViewCell`, and I have `UIStepper` and `UILabel` in the custom cell. I don't know how to check which stepper was clicked. So is it a way to know from which cell stepper was clicked?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        if ([nib count] > 0) {
            cell = self.tbcell;
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: UITableViewCell *cell;
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        if ([nib count] > 0) {
            cell = self.tbcell;
        }
        
    }
    
    
   
    return cell;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An alternative is:

In the method that gets fired when the UIStepper value changes (e.g. @max_, above), you can do the following:

> ```
> - (IBAction)stepperValueDidChanged:(UIStepper *)sender {
>     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[[sender superview] superview];
>     // assuming your view controller is a subclass of UITableViewController, for example.
>     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
> }
> ```

Comment: +1 much better than setting the tag to the row index because it works for sectioned tables too. and it doesn't rely on state saved in the view

Comment: I understand that this does not work in IOS 7. Can anyone suggest an IOS 7 solution?

Comment: It works in IOS if you use [[[sender superview] superview] superview]

Answer (score 0):

```
[step addTarget:self action:@selector(someAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (void) someAction:(UIStepper *) stepper {
    NSLog(@"stepper clicked");
}
```